# girlfriend / boyfriend confusion

Tags: confusables

During a discussion, I was trying to make a point; I told the woman I was speaking to,

> You're wrong! I have a girlfriend who plays videogames!

This backfired; she assumed I had a girlfriend. How does one refer to a female/male friend?

Comment: 'I know a girl'

Comment: @Mynamite but we are friends, I want to express that information too

Comment: 'I have a friend, she plays videogames' 'Girlfriend' is generally taken to mean a girl that you are in a relationship with. So add a bit of background - I was at school with her, she's my sister's friend, I know her from work etc. But maybe if you're talking to a girl in a bar you don't need to give all the information at once?

Comment: to lose (simple past : I lost - past participle : lost) - to refer

Comment: You may find [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/35/32) useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I have a female friend who plays video games.*
*I have a friend who loves video games, who is a girl.*
*I have a friend, and she loves video games.*

There's really no need to use girlfriend when speaking about female friends. There are so many alternatives these days to describe platonic relationships.